# LASSO when there is correlation across individuals at the same time

Tags: panel-data, lasso

Hi suppose I want to investigate a problem like this: 
There are 100 cilantro farms in Michigan, indexed *i*.

There are 200 month of observation,  for each of the farm's monthly cilantro harvest productions, in kilogram.

Each cilantro farm is treated with 70 different growth chemicals, the chemicals are applied in various amounts at the beginning of each month and the harvest is done at the end of month. I want to run a LASSO regression to find out which growth chemical is more important.

The problem is there is clearly correlation in the error term (e_*it*), contemporaneously across the N farms, so that when at one point in time,  (e_*it*) could be universally high for all farms, all universally low for all farms. Why? Because of the bee population, wind direction, pest migration pattern, quality of the shared harvest equipment, can influence **all the farms at the same time**, and these are unobserved and are captured in the error term.

How do I transform this type of panel data before running LASSO, so that the contemporanous correlation in the error term across farm is addressed?

This should be a classical panel data problem. Any paper reference in pdf format, with particular emphasis on the application of LASSO in this context is appreciated.

Perhaps a standard panel technique is to assume there are two types of errors, u_t and e_it, that are both i.i.d. normal, but I cannot find any reference on how to do LASSO on this setup. Nor can I find any statistical package, SAS or STATA, that could handle this situation for LASSO.

Comment: Assumptions about correlations are needed. Maybe (1) assume the with farm correlation ($e_{it}$ and $e_{it'}$) follows AR(1), (2) compound symmetry for correlation between farms, i.e., corr ($e_{it},e_{i't}$) = r. Then you can fit the model.

Comment: Don't think this is gonna work since nobody knows what the value of the r parameter should be. Perhaps a standard panel technique is to assume there are two types of errors, u_t and e_it, that are both i.i.d. normal, but I cannot find any reference on how to do LASSO on this setup. Nor can I find any statistical package, SAS or STATA, that could handle this situation for LASSO.

Comment: You do not need to know r, the program can estimate it for you. it is one of parameters in the model.

Comment: Sorry not what I'm looking for, don't wanna impose correlation structure r, is there a way to do Random Effect estimation, as done in the panel data analysis, with the standard assumptions in panel data analysis with random effects, but with LASSO?

Comment: Could you write your model mathematically? then we can discuss and modify it.